# What's the one liner for assigning a std::shared_ptr from the result of a function?

Tags: c++

There's gotta be a more idiomatic way to do this:

```
Potato SpecialPotato();
std::shared_ptr<Potato> givePotato()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Potato> ret;
    *ret = SpecialPotato();
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: I think you mean "assigning the result of a function to a `std::shared_ptr`". The direction of assignment is from the right side to the left side.

Comment: Is `SpecialPotato()` meant to be a function creating a specialization (derived class) of `Potato`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`*ret = SpecialPotato();` is not going to work as `ret` is just a null pointer as it was default constructed.  If you want to return a `std::shared_ptr<Potato>` that points to a `Potato` with the value that `SpecialPotato()` returned then you can use `std::make_shared` like

```
std::shared_ptr<Potato> givePotato()
{
    return std::make_shared<Potato>(SpecialPotato());
}
```

This will dynamically allocate a `Potato`, initialize it with the return of `SpecialPotato()` and then return the `shared_ptr`.

---

Do note that if `SpecialPotato()` is supposed to return a type that is derived from `Potato` then you can't return a `Potato`.  That will [slice the object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) and you you lose the derived part of the object.  When returning a derived type as a parent type you need to use a pointer/pointer-like type like

```
std::shared_ptr<Potato> SpecialPotato()
{
    return std::make_shared<SpecialPotatoType>(/* constructor parameters here */);
}
```

Comment: OP asked for a _one liner_. Is that function really needed?

Comment: @user0042 I have no idea.  The OP was using a function with 3 lines so I gave them a function with one.  It's up to them to decide if they even need a function.

Comment: Seems OP want's to use `SpecialPotato` as prototype or another function that returns a shared pointer creating a _special sort of potato_. I can't fully decipher what they actually want.

Comment: @user0042 Seems simple enough.  They are using 3 lines right now and want to simplify it.  If it is not what they want they will probably comment.

Comment: Looks a bit like a XY problem for me. Voted to close as _unclear_.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`std::make_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared):

```
Potato SpecialPotato();
std::shared_ptr<Potato> givePotato()
{
   return std::make_shared<Potato>(SpecialPotato());
}
```

It has the pro to build the `std::shared_ptr` and the object copy in one pass. Moreover, the copy may be optimized out.

Comment: What's the advantage about taking a copy?

Comment: @user0042 not my design: `SpecialPotato()` returns by value. Without any optimization, building a `std::shared_ptr` from a value copies the value. Why the downvote?